# Display upside down

Tags: display

Display is upside down but cursor is ok but the cursor clicks elsewhere as it were upside down as well.

You can see cursor in the pic

[image: [You can see cursor in the pic]

Comment: check it out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328248/screen-detection-and-mouse-reverse-x-y-axis-kali-linux

Comment: Does that happen with the login manager as well?

Comment: Yes that happens with login manager as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem

```
sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this is happening to you, but you should be able to fix that with the following commands:

- Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- Enter the following command:

  ```
  xrandr --output $(xrandr | grep 'primary' | cut -d' ' -f1) --rotate normal
  ```

  This should return the rotation back to normal
- If the this doesn't help try the inverted command:

  ```
  xrandr --output $(xrandr | grep 'primary' | cut -d' ' -f1) --rotate inverted
  ```

Comment: Or go to ***Settings->Devices->Displays*** and choose Landscape or Landscape(flipped) (whichever solves the problem).

Comment: Inverted command worked now display is back to normal but the cursor is upside down